# onmouseover fails in chrome when posting or leaving page

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have onmouseover and onmouseout attributes on pictures on page. When submitting onmouseover and onmouseout cause images to fail (returns image source not found icon)

```
<input type="image" src="../../Content/Resources/save.png" onmouseover="mouseOverForImage('save', '../../Content/Resources/save_mouse_over.png')" 
               onmouseout = "mouseOverForImage('save', '../../Content/Resources/save.png')" id="save"
               title = "Save" />
```

And Javascript:

```
function mouseOverForImage(imgId, imgSrcs) {
        document.getElementById(imgId).src = imgSrcs;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code here, or a link to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Are you positive the images are at those locations? Try going to them directly to ensure they exist.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Linked question was removed.

Comment: I'm sure they exist. It fails only when server is processing submit request

Comment: This only happens on Chrome? It works in other browsers? And is your form submit handled by Ajax, or just a standard POST submit?

Comment: Yes, this happens only in chrome. It's a standard post submit

Comment: And have you confirmed that a Chrome extension is not causing the problem? Running Chrome without extensions, maybe on another computer?

Comment: We have same problem on 5 computers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
function mouseOverForImage(imgId, imgSrcs) { 

    var image = new Image(); 

    image.src = imgSrcs; 

    image.onload = function() { 
        document.getElementById(imgId).src = imgSrcs; 
    }; 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've made a [**page on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJwYY/3/) to test your issue (note that you need to **run** the page in order to see the images with relative paths, that's a jsfiddle issue happening in all browsers).

Hover the [+] image button (it will turn into [?]) and click it. While the page is being loaded you can mouseover/out/over/out/over... as many times as you want and it will work: the image will change and no 404 will occur.

I am using Chrome 20.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. What's your Chrome version and can you reproduce the issue in Safari? I recall Webkit had a bug that displayed images quite randomly...
2. Have you posted the code *exactly*? Are you 100% sure that there's no missing quote, or "0" instead of "o", or some issue with letter case?
3. When you submit the form, does your page's (or iframe's) URL change at the same time? If so - your relative paths won't work anymore and you'll get your 404. Can you test it by setting a full path to the image's src? Maybe also log the current url?
4. Can some other code (onsubmit event?) interfere with your form? Can you post more code or create a jsfiddle that reproduces your issue?
5. Do we/I understand your problem correctly? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In place of using mouseover and mouseout events try using mouseenter and mouseleave. It usually works in these types of problem.